# Calling Error messages when cross contract calling in ink

Tags: ink, rust

I want to call Error messages from different contract I am calling in ink! using
the '?' operator.
However it gives me the following Error:

```
`?` couldn't convert the error to `contract::Error`
  --> lib.rs:77:107
   |
77 |   self.diff_contract.method(value_1, value_2)?;
   |                                   ^ the trait `std::convert::From<diff_contract::diff_contract::Error>` is not implemented for `contract::Error`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::FromResidual<std::result::Result<std::convert::Infallible, diff_contract::diff_contract::Error>>` for `std::result::Result<[u8; 32], contract::Error>`
```

I guess I have to declare that I want to use the Error handling of the other contract in my original smart contract?
If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have different errors inside the function's body, you need to define the rules for converting one error into another.

For example, if `diff_contract.method(value_1, value_2)` returns `Resutl<(), DiffError>`, and your function returns `Result<(), MyCurrentError>`, you need to convert `DiffError` into `MyCurrentError`.

If you define `MyCurrentError`, you can implement the `From<DiffError>` trait, and the Rust will convert your error under the hood. You can check the example [here](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/contracts/src/traits/errors/psp22.rs#L48).

But if `MyCurrentError` is defined by someone else, you can't implement foreign traits for foreign types. In that case, you need manually map one error into another.